# How to integrate mobile website in app framework? Which tools exist?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We are currently developing a mobile website to support the experience of our event participants (they can see the program there but also log into our system and send messages between participants etc). We would now like to integrate this mobile website in an app, basically because people are more used to download apps than storing weblinks on their mobile or tablet home screen. In addition we want to send push messages duing the event.

My question is now twofold:

a) is this at all possible? I could imagine it is possible on Android but not on IOS as Apple protects the system and does not allow to have too much mobile content in an app.
b) which frameworks / tools / websites exist in which I can integrate my mobile version in an app? For Android, and if a) is also possible also for IOS.

For all those who are questioning why this guy is not developing the apps right away, here is the true but sad answer: we do not have a real budget for it and web programming is the only thing I am capable of at the moment (regarding programming of course :)).

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Best
Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

be careful with bundling your website inside an app, as per the [Apple App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) 2.12:

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Apple is very strict when it comes to this. Your best bet is to download Apple's book on Swift and start learning some native programming starting today!

Comment: Hi Danny,  many thanks for your answer. I expected this with IOS. Do you have any recommendations on the easiest way to create an Android app based on a mobile website? Do the app builder website proovide me with all the functionality? Thanks again, Danny.